# CERT_UNTRUSTED Error Response from Amazon SNS from Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, push-notification, cordova-plugins, amazon-sns

I am using `sns-mobile` to register mobile device with Amazon SNS. I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.evanshortiss.com/sns-push-notifications-using-nodejs/) on SNS Push Notifications using nodejs.

The code for creating the SNS object looks like the following:

```
var myApp = new SNS({
    platform: SNS.SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS.ANDROID,
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    apiVersion: '2010-03-31',
    accessKeyId: config.sns.key_id,
    secretAccessKey: config.sns.secret_key_id,
    platformApplicationArn: config.sns.arn
});
```

The code for registering/adding the user or device in this case is the following:

```
// Add the user to SNS
myApp.addUser(deviceId, null, function(err, endpointArn) {
    // SNS returned an error
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            status: 'error occurred registering device'
        });
    }

    // Tell the user everything is ok
    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'ok'
    });
});
```

The error logged to the console is the following:

```
{ [Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED]
  message: 'CERT_UNTRUSTED',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  hostname: 'sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  time: Sun Mar 08 2015 17:13:44 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time),
  statusCode: undefined }
```

I tried looking around for reasons why this may be happening, but keep coming across claims that it is a problem with nodejs.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with node **v0.10.34** (Node.js). This should be fixed in **v0.10.35**.

```
changelog: 2014.12.22, Version 0.10.35 (Stable)

tls: re-add 1024-bit SSL certs removed by f9456a2 (Chris Dickinson)
```

Solution: 
**Upgrade to [node 0.10.35](http://blog.nodejs.org/2014/12/23/node-v0-10-35-stable/)**.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with SES. I ended up having to use node v0.10.33 (this was back in December, 2014). So, if you just recently updated, I would just use a previous release until the bug is worked out.

(Some of the conversation on GitHub from that issue might be helpful...https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8894)